# What causes an enemy pilot to appear on the minimap?

Tags: titanfall

While playing Titanfall, one can often gets periodic updates on the positions of enemy pilots by their appearance on the minimap as thick red dots.

Under what conditions can a pilot appear on the minimap?

Does shooting at non-pilot enemies cause an enemy pilot to appear? or is it from a friendly pilot using a radar pulse?

Some levels have spy drones occasionally flying around, do those expose the player's position to the enemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware:

- Firing any non-silenced weapon shows you for a short time.
- Melee attacks as well as using explosives won't reveal you.
- Using the jetpack won't reveal you either.
- Being spotted (items or perks) will reveal you for a short time as well.